# Bash script array to csv

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, csv

I want to do comma separated string from my array. In my script i collecting data to array `outputArr` and then i want to `echo` it to check it out, but now i'm stuck. I want to print it on console using:

`echo ${outputArr[*]}`

But i'm getting wrong output. So i'm trying to debug it and write it like this:

```
echo ${outputArr[0]}
echo ${outputArr[1]}
echo ${outputArr[*]}
echo "-------------"
```

OK here is my output:

```
Terminally Yours
2204
 2204nally Yours
-------------
```

and other example:

```
Alfa
1491
 1491
-------------
```

Why this is overwritten with space in the beginning? Of course my goal is (finally):

```
Alfa;1491
```

In this point:

```
Alfa1491
```

**EDIT:**

```
while read -r line
do
    singleLine=$line
    if [[ $singleLine =~ $regexVenueName ]]
    then
        singleLine=${singleLine/<span id=\"ctl00_MainContent_lbPartner\" class=\"Partner\">/}
        singleLine=${singleLine/<\/span> <br \/><br \/>/}
        partnerVenueNameOutput+="$singleLine"
        outputArr[0]=$singleLine
    fi
done < "$f"
```

Comment: Have you tried quoting your variables? `echo "${outputArr[0]}"`

Comment: Your array elements end with carriage returns, probably because you read from a file with DOS line endings or captured output from a command that used carriage returns.

Comment: @fedorqui - Yep, didn't work.

Comment: @chepner - maybe... how can i remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array contains elements with carriage returns:

```
$ foo=($'\rterminally yours' $'\r2204')
$ echo "${foo[0]}"
terminally yours
$ echo "${foo[1]}"
2204
$ echo "${foo[*]}"
2204inally yours
```

For your code, you can add the following to remove the carriage return from the variable:

```
singleLine=${singleLine//$'\r'/}
```

Comment: There probably it. How can i remove it? I read my file line by line from html file downloaded with wget. I update my answer adding some code.

Answer (score 2):

To remove any trailing carriage returns from each array element, try

```
outputArray=( "${outputArray[@]%$'\r'}" )
```

However, it would probably be better to examine how `outputArray` is set in the first place and prevent the carriage returns from being added in the first place. If you are reading from a file that uses DOS line endings, try "cleaning" it first using `dos2unix`.